# array_map and trim not trimming white space from values

Tags: php, arrays, trim

This function below returns a string of values comma separated

`$key_1_value = get_post_meta(422,'keywords',true);`

The output in my browser looks like
`red, white, blue, blue two  , green, yellow, purple, magenta                                                                                                             , cyan, black`

I'm trying to trim the white space before and after all values.

So I used this code to try and trim the whitespace but it's still there. Why won't this trim the values?

```
$test = array($key_1_value);
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$test);
print_r($trimmed_array);
```

Comment: Better `var_dump($test)` it.

Comment: Try `$trimmed = implode(',', array_map('trim', explode(',',$key_1_value)));` or `$trimmed = preg_replace('\s*,\s*', ',', $key_1_value);`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`$key_1_value` is a string representation and not an array or a string with quoted values, you have to explode it into array items, and not just put it inside an array call, then it becomes a proper array

```
$test = explode(",", $key_1_value);
$trimmed_array = array_map('trim', $test);
print_r($trimmed_array);
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that explode created an array I thought it only modified the string

Comment: explode's prototype is `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`: hence it returns an array